# How to solve the index problem of input and label prepared with for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am doing the structure I created with the for loop in the homepage.blade file. I have such a problem. Let's say I created 5 inputs. When I press the 5th label after the structures are created, the 1.input is always activated. How do I solve this?

**homepage.blade.php**

```
 <h4>Checkbox</h4>
  @include('items.checkbox')
  @include('items.checkbox', array('error' => true))
  @include('items.checkbox', array('label' => 'Inline Centered', 'labelClass'=> 'label-centered'))
```

**checkbox.blade.php**

```
<fieldset class="form-group checkbox @if (!empty($width)){{$width}}@endif @if(!empty($labelClass)) {{$labelClass}} @endif">
  <input id="checkbox{{$i}}" type="checkbox" placeholder="Option text" />
  <div class="wrapper">
    <label for="checkbox{{$i}}">@if (!empty($label)) {{$label}} @else Checkbox @endif *</label>
    <small>Helper text goes here</small>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The first thing to check is the source of the page - what does the generated HTML look like? Are `id`s and `for`s correct?